# Expose a single local file to the internet using command line

Tags: command-line, file-sharing, file-server

I want to let a friend to download a file from my mac. Just one file. Is there a way to expose a specific local file from my ubuntu or mac so that my friend could just enter my IP and port in a browser and get the file I've exposed?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't trivial. Please [edit] your question and give us more details: is your friend on the same network as you or does this need to happen over the internet? If the latter, have you forwarded the relevant ports in your router? Is either of the three machines (your Mac, your Ubuntu and your friend's) accessible over the internet? Do you have any kind of webserver running? How about ssh? Does this need to be done from an Ubuntu machine or a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Your PC `cat file | nc -l 11111`

Your friend's PC `nc -i 3 your_IP_address 11111 > file`

Of course that'll work only if you have a public IP address and the port is not firewalled.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, not a trivial task with local area network firewalls and such to get to the file locally. I use Google Drive and share a link that can be for one person specifically, using email address, or for whoever has a link to the file. This way, your data is protected by Google and you can send an email link to a file that avoids overloading an email with an attachment.

https://www.google.com/drive/

Comment: You can optionally (symmetric) encrypt the file with gpg or even password protected zip file if you do not trust google. And share the password over another medium.